# Remove telephone field in PDF Print-outs in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, pdf

Look at my screenshot. In `System >> Configuration >> Customer Configuration >> Address templates >> PDF` i removed the telephone lines.

But still the telephone numbers shows up in the Invoice PDF under `Ship too / Bill to` (client information).

How do i remove telephone lines completely from the PDF Print-outs in Magento 1.9?

[image]

Comment: This is the right method, and it does work. Make sure you are editing the right store view, or you don't have any module overriding the PDF generation.

Comment: its strange. I configured this under Default Config. I use Fooman PDF customizer but they say also i have to use this method. I don't know what to do..?

Comment: I have just tried on a fresh clean install and it works first time. I would disable the Fooman module, and try again, just to rule it out. Then if it still doesn't work, it has to be another module.

Comment: and you removed this line from the address template `{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}` ?

Comment: Correct, I removed exactly that from the PDF field `{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}`

Comment: no its still not working, i don't know where to look or what to do.. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23689/discussion-between-mayers-and-meez).

Comment: it says _You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq._ so i can't use this..?

Comment: Get in touch with me, we can discuss this further

Comment: But how? Thanks

Comment: My website is linked in my profile, you can contact me through there

Comment: FWIW, I just had to remove the telephone number from the billing address on PDF print-outs for a client and simply removing `{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|` from that section as per your screenshot worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't overwrite the default settings on store view level.

If you don't overwrite it, you have a bigger problem, somewhere in your code.